# Reading words from file into dynamic char with linked lists

Tags: c, dynamic, linked-list, char

I am trying to read data from a file and save the data into a linked list. We are not able to make the char word into a static char. We have to make it dynamic to accept a word of any length using char *word. I am having trouble reading the words from the file and saving it into the dynamic char. I have done this before with static char which is easy. Here is the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    char *word;
    struct node *next;
};

struct codex {
    char *word;
    struct codex *next;
};

struct node *loadWords(FILE *stream);

int main() {
    struct node *head;
    FILE *stream;
    head = loadWords(stream);
    return 0;
}

struct node *loadWords(FILE *stream) {
    struct node *poem;
    struct node *temp;
    char *words, *currentWord;
    size_t chrCount;
    stream = fopen("hw8.data", "r");

    rewind(stream);

    while(!feof(stream)) {
        if(temp = (struct node*)calloc(1, sizeof(struct node)) == NULL) {
            printf("ERROR - Could not allocate memory.\n");
            exit(0);
        }
        getline(&words, &chrCount, stream);
        currentWord = strtok(words, " ");
        strcpy(temp->word, words);
        head->next = temp;
        head = head->next;
    }

    return poem;
}
```

How am I to do this dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This uses getline to read each line from the file. If `words` is set to NULL and `chrCount` is set to zero, getline will allocate the memory needed to store the line from the file.
As the line is tokenized, a structure is calloc'd. `strdup` will allocate the memory to store the token and copy the token into the structure.
The new structure is added to the end of the linked list. The memory allocated for words is released and words and chrCount are reset for the next line.
The loop will continue as long as getline returns a value greater than 0.
In main, the list is traversed printing each word and then traversed again, freeing the allocated memory.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    char * word;
    struct node* next;
};

struct node *loadWords(FILE *stream);

int main()
{
    FILE *stream = NULL;
    struct node *head;
    struct node *temp;
    struct node *loop;
    head = loadWords(stream);
    if ( head == NULL) {
        return 1;
    }
    temp = head;//print each word
    while ( temp != NULL) {
        printf ( "%s\n", temp->word);
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    temp = head;// free memory
    while ( temp != NULL) {
        loop = temp->next;
        free ( temp->word);
        free ( temp);
        temp = loop;
    }
    return 0;
}

struct node *loadWords(FILE *stream) {
    struct node *loop = NULL;
    struct node *temp = NULL;
    struct node *head = NULL;
    char *words = NULL;
    char *currentWord;
    size_t chrCount = 0;
    if ( ( stream = fopen("hw8.data", "r")) == NULL) {
        printf ("could not open file\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    while( getline( &words, &chrCount, stream) > 0) {//read a line from file
        currentWord = strtok(words, " ");//get first token
        while ( currentWord != NULL) {//loop through tokens
            if((temp = calloc(1, sizeof(struct node))) == NULL) {
                printf("ERROR - Could not allocate memory.\n");
                exit(0);
            }
            temp->word = strdup ( currentWord);//allocate memory and copy token to word
            if ( head == NULL) {
                head = temp;//first structure
            }
            else {
                loop = head;
                while ( loop->next != NULL) {//loop to last structure
                    loop = loop->next;//add structure to end
                }
                loop->next = temp;
            }
            currentWord = strtok(NULL, " ");//next token
        }
        free ( words);//release memory
        chrCount = 0;//so readline will allocate memory for next line
        words = NULL;
    }
    fclose ( stream);
    return head;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to know how to allocate memory, I'll assume the issue is that you don't know how much to allocate for each word.  (Similar ideas apply for reading in lines).

If you had some idea about about how big each word could possibly be, you could statically allocate that, and then once each word has been read in, dynamically allocate the correct size you need.

Otherwise, you could read in your text one character at a time until you have finished a word, so that you can increase your buffer as needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct node {
    char *word;
    struct node *next;
};

//struct codex unused

struct node *loadWords(FILE *stream);

int main(void) {
    struct node *head;
    FILE *stream = fopen("hw8.data", "r");//No sense to pass arguments If you do not open at caller side
    head = loadWords(stream);
    fclose(stream);
    {//test print and release
        struct node *p = head;
        while(p){
            struct node *temp = p->next;
            puts(p->word);
            free(p->word);
            free(p);
            p = temp;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

struct node *loadWords(FILE *stream) {
    struct node *head = NULL, *curr, *temp;
    char *words = NULL, *currentWord;
    size_t chrCount = 0;

    rewind(stream);

    while(getline(&words, &chrCount, stream) != -1){
        currentWord = strtok(words, " \t\n");
        while(currentWord != NULL){
            if((temp = calloc(1, sizeof(struct node))) == NULL) {
                fprintf(stderr, "ERROR - Could not allocate memory.\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            temp->word = strdup(currentWord);//malloc and strcpy
            if(head == NULL){
                curr = head = temp;
            } else {
                curr = curr->next = temp;
            }
            currentWord = strtok(NULL, " \t\n");
        }
    }
    free(words);

    return head;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Explaining the idea :**

My idea is to link characters of each word in a linked list named `Word` . Then , i put each word in another linked list named `Node` . ( And of course everything will be allocated dynamically ).

An example of text :

> Hello World, here.

Our algorithm will do something like this :

`H->e->l->l->o` -> `W->o->r->l->d` -> `h->e->r->e`

**Note** : words are separated by either space or standard punctuation , so i used `isspace` and `ispunct` functions .

**Here is my code :**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
struct Node {
    char * word;
    struct Node* next;
};

struct Word {
    char chr;
    struct Word* next;
};


int main (void)
{
   static const char filename[] = "C:\\a.txt";
   FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");
   Node *list = 0;
   Node **last = &list;
   Word *word = 0;
   int list_size = 0;
   int word_size = 0;
   if ( file != NULL )
   {
      int ch, inword = 0;
      while ( 1 )
      {
         ch = fgetc(file);
         if ( isspace(ch) || ispunct(ch) || ch == EOF )
         {
            if ( inword )
            {
               inword = 0;
               char * string = (char *) malloc(word_size+1);
               for(int i=word_size-1; i>=0; i--) {
                   string[i]= word->chr;
                   Word * aux = word;
                   word = word->next;
                   free(aux);
               }
               string[word_size] = '\0';
               Node * aux = (Node *) malloc(sizeof(Node));
               aux->word = string;
               aux->next = 0;
               *last = aux;
               last = & aux->next;
               word_size = 0;
            }
            if(ch == EOF)
                break;
         }
         else
         {
            inword = 1;
            Word * aux = word;
            word = (Word *) malloc(sizeof(Word));
            word->chr = ch;
            word->next = aux;
            word_size++;
         }
      }
      fclose(file);
      for(Node * aux = list ; aux; aux=aux->next) {
          puts(aux->word);
      }
      getchar();
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Hope I helped .

Happy Coding :D

Comment: I have worked on this code in visual c++ , so may be i have included some features of c++ accidentally . Lol , i used `true ` in my code , i will edit it to `1` . @BLUEPIXY please tell me if there is another feature used in my code which exits in c++ and not in c .

Comment: You can switch the setting of compiler options.